# extract particular columns from matrix and store it as a new matrix in C

Tags: c, memcpy, lapack, blas

I have a matrix stored as a dynamic array i.e. double *inputMat. I know its number of rows and columns through which I can extract any particular column. Now issue is, I have a set of columns to be extracted and stored into another dynamic array. How to do this? I am writing a portion of my code for reference:

```
double *extractMatrix(double *inputMat,int rows, int *columnIndex, int columnTotal)
{      
   double *outputMat=malloc(sizeof(double)*rows*columnTotal);
   for(int i=0; i<columnTotal; i++)
       memcpy(outputMat, &inputMat[rows*columnIndex[i]],rows*sizeof(double));
   return outputMat;
}
```

The columnIndex contains indices of columns to be extracted from matrix. ColumnTotal is the size of columnIndex array. However this will copy only one particular column of inputMat into outputMat and then probably get overwritten. I want a complete array of all those columns in columnIndex. I am working with lapack and BLAS libraries. If there is an inbuilt way to do this then please share.

Comment: Nothing.  cols represent the number of columns in inputMat. It is not needed in current scenario.  I will remove it. Please see the edited version.

Comment: `memcpy(outputMat, ...` destination always the same,should change per `i`.

Comment: If you are passing `double *` as a parameter, why are `rows` and `columnTotal` needed at all? Wouldn't `size_t size` be more appropriate? You essentially have an *array of doubles* (albeit technically a *pointer to double*). You should simply need the pointer, `size` and `columnIndex`). You can then index it to extract columns however you like.

Comment: @chux. How to change that ? Can we something like memcpy(outputMat+rows*i*sizeof(double),....) to iterate the memory address of outputMat

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: columnTotal represent the size of columnIndex i.e no. of columns in outputMat while rows are number of rows in inputMat / outputMat. It is useful in memory allocation. I want to copy chunks of memory(columns) from different regions of  input array.

Comment: Ah, you do need `rows` and `columnTotal` for the "concept" of columns. Sorry to confuse. Without `rows` and `columnTotal`, you don't have a measure of what offset to apply. If you are modeling `arr[i][j]` you will need `arr[i*j+j]` to model it from a 1D block.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Exactly.

Comment: If I understand you you want something like `int n = 0; for (int i = *columnIndex; i < rows * columnTotal; i += columnTotal) memcpy (outputMat[n++], inputMat[i], sizeof inputMat[i]);` (you can pre-calculate the values to pretty it up) (this assumes `*columnIndex` is a pointer to a number for the column -- *zero based* -- it is unclear why it is passed as a pointer)

Answer (score 1):

Your basic goal is to index your *array of double* (actually a *pointer to double*) as if it were a 2D array. You want to do this in a function extracting a certain column `columnIndex` and dynamically allocating a block of memory to hold the values that make up that column (`rows` number of values) and return a pointer to the newly allocated block.

Your approach is on the right track, your indexing is just off. It is quite a bit easier to handle the indexing in the `for` loop itself. The basic approach is:

```
int n = 0;
for (int i = colindex; i < rows * cols; i += cols)
    output[n++] = input[i];
```

(that assumes `n < INT_MAX` values in the column -- adjust as needed)

Putting together a small example that does what it looks like you are trying to do, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *getcol (const int *a, const int rows, const int col, const int ncols)
{
    int sz = rows * ncols,
        n = 0,   /* output index */
        *out = malloc (rows * sizeof *a);

    if (out)
        for (int i = col; i < sz; i += ncols)  /* index with loop vars */
            out[n++] = a[i];                   /* assign column values */

    return out;
}

int main (void) {

    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
        rows = 3,                   /* simulate a 3x3 with 9 values */
        cols = sizeof a / (rows * sizeof *a),
        colidx = 1,                 /* zero based index of wanted column */
        *output = NULL;

    if ((output = getcol (a, rows, colidx, cols))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            printf (" %2d\n", output[i]);
        free (output);  /* don't forget to free memory */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the function parameters are in the order you have listed -- but use shorter names. Preferably you would swap the order so that `columnIndex` is last, but that's up to you, the column you want need not be passed as a pointer and there is no need for `memcpy` where simple assignment will work. Also, the column index you want is passed as a *zero based index*)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_idx_1d_as_2d
  2
  5
  8
```

(which is the 2nd column of the simulated 3x3 array from the 9 values)

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I heard that memcpy is faster than "for loop" indexing. Since the matrices I am dealing with, are very large (size >= 500x500) ,  copying may be bit slower with regular "for loop" especially when I am calling this function many times in my actual algorithm. What I want, is to merge different columns. I don't know how to do it with memcpy. I need some iterator kind of thing in it like explicitly making it to copy after "n" elements.

Comment: I don't know where you got your info, but you can't `memcpy` non-sequential bytes, so you are not going to benefit from using `memcpy` at all to pick columns out of a block of memory when each column value is separated by `cols * sizeof val` bytes. Do I understand your problem wrong?

Comment: Now if you need to merge 500 columns out of a 500+ column 2D array into a separate 500 column 2D array, then yes, `memcpy` is useful because you can `memcpy` 500 values at a time (as adjacent column values are adjacent), but to pick non-adjacent columns it isn't of any use.